# Define your own latitude and longitude projection

Tags: coordinate-system, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I am converting (rotating) vectors from Lambert to latlon (and viceversa) in Python. But in Basemap or Cartopy, I see that you do not define the lat and lon projections, you just define your Lambert, but the system always take lat and lon as (I guess) the WGS-84 datum. For example, from this example here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878564/how-can-i-rotate-vectors-onto-a-basemap-map-projection):

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up map projection
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-15.,llcrnrlat=46.,urcrnrlon=15.,urcrnrlat=59.,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=40.,lat_2=50.,lon_0=-50.,
        resolution ='l')

# Calculate positions of vectors on map projection 
x,y = m(lon,lat)
```

How can I define my own latitude, longitude system (I want a spherical one, not the ellipsoid of WGS-84) in order to perform the conversions from my Lambert to my latlon? I can use Cartopy, Proj4 or whatever Python tool you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `matplotlib-basemap` as you do with your attached code, you already have the functionality of `direct` and `inverse` coordinate conversion.

Conversion from (long,lat) to `lcc` projection:

```
lon = [8, 10]
lat = [47, 49]
x,y = m(lon,lat)
```

Computation check, i.e. conversion from `lcc` (x,y) to (long, lat):

```
lon2,lat2 = m(x, y, inverse=True)
```

You will get:

```
lon2: [8.000000000000005, 9.999999999999995]
lat2: [47.0, 49.00000000000001]
```

**Edit**

If you want to use spherical earth with radius = 6370997 m, you can specify that as an option:

```
m_lcc = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-15.,llcrnrlat=46.,urcrnrlon=15.,urcrnrlat=59.,
    projection='lcc',lat_1=40.,lat_2=50.,lon_0=-50.,
    resolution ='l', rsphere = 6370997)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that all this is assuming a lon lat system with the ellipsoid of reference (WPS84), and I want to create a sphere where I define my lat lon. I need that to rotate vectors, as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079254/cartopy-vector-from-lambert-to-latlon

Comment: Lat/lon on WGS84 or spherical earth do not make much difference in normal use. What is your use case?

Comment: @David Spherical earth option is possible by specifying an option `rsphere` with value of the earth radius.

Comment: That you, @swatchai. Would it be too much if you can check this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079254/cartopy-vector-from-lambert-to-latlon?